# Erlang: check on which scheduler a process is running?

Tags: erlang, profiling

I could use erlang:trace/3 to keep track of which scheduler the processes are running at any given time and then use the timestamp+pid to get the scheduler id but is there a simpler/more efficient way?

perhaps something like self/0 that returns the scheduler ID instead of the process ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are may be looking for `erlang:system_info(scheduler_id)`.